# Subscribing PubNub in python

Tags: python-2.7, publish-subscribe, pubnub

I am making a small voting system in python and me plan was to have clients that ask the user for there vote and send it off using pubnub. I then wanted to make an application that will recive the votes and count them all up but I cannot find a way to receive the messages. Am I doing this right or is there a better way thanks for your time.

Comment: You have a few options.  It is recommended to use [PubNub Storage and Playback](http://www.pubnub.com/how-it-works/storage-and-playback/) via your server to aggregate voting totals.  You'll grab the history on the channel and tally the vote totals.  `pubnub.history({ channel : "...", callback : function, start : "TIMETOKEN" })`.  Using PubNub History method is the easiest option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PubNub Voting Tally with Python

You have a few options. It is recommended to use PubNub Storage and Playback via your server to aggregate voting totals. You'll grab the history on the channel and tally the vote totals.

### PubNub PIP Package

```
pip install pubnub
```

### Tally Votes in Python

```
from Pubnub import Pubnub

## Init PubNub
pubnub = Pubnub( publish_key="demo", subscribe_key="demo", ssl_on=False )

## Total Votes
last_tt      = 0
total_votes  = 0
vote_chan    = "my_vote_channel"
results_chan = "my_vote_channel.results"

## Tally Callback Function (Sum up the Votes...)
def tally(response):
    print(response)
    total_votes += len(response[0])
    last_tt = response[1]

## Loop Continuously on the last known TIMETOKEN
pubnub.history({ channel : vote_chan, callback : tally, start : last_tt })

## Periodically Publish to the Results Channel 
pubnub.publish({ channel : results_chan, message : { "total" : total_votes } })
```

Using PubNub History method is the easiest option.